# How to synchronize configuration between git setups?

Tags: git, configuration

I'm new to git, and I'm doubting how can I synchronize config files between developers.

Let's say I want **all** developers to have core.autocrlf set to true, or the same commit template, how can I do it?

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: What platform are your developers on? Is it homogeneous?

Comment: At the moment, Linux. But it is possible that some wind*ws developers will be working in the same project.

But I also want other configuration flags to be homogeneous between the team, like the commit template.

Thanks

Comment: Check the git config files into Visual SourceSafe.

Comment: Visual SourceSafe? I'm using linux Jay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such guarantee in a DVCS (as in "Distributed"), since [local settings beat global settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881551/how-is-the-git-config-evaluated-when-commit-ing).

But in a closed environment (where the population of developers have accessed to a common and shared set of resources), you can:

- encapsulate the `git init` process (to [use a template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093077/default-config-settings-for-a-new-git-repository), for common settings)
- Force the `GIT_CONFIG` environment variable to a shared read-only file (on Linux, accessed through Samba from Windows users), to force all config settings to be read from there.

This is not a full-proofed solution, but it can get you started.