# git push remote: warning: hooks.mailinglist has multiple values

Tags: git, hook, gitolite

I have just upgraded from using gitosis to gitolite. Email notifications are working for all repos but for the gitolite-admin repo I get this waring when I push (the push is good):

```
$ git push
remote: warning: hooks.announcelist has multiple values
remote: error: cannot overwrite multiple values with a single value
remote:        Use a regexp, --add or --set-all to change hooks.announcelist.
remote: warning: hooks.mailinglist has multiple values
remote: error: cannot overwrite multiple values with a single value
remote:        Use a regexp, --add or --set-all to change hooks.mailinglist.
To git@myserver:gitolite-admin
    5629bf0..98f3977  master -> master
$
```

In the gitolite.conf file I have

```
repo gitolite-admin
RW+ = @gitadmin
config hooks.mailinglist = "me@foo.com"
congig hooks.announcelist = "me@ffo.com"
config hooks.emailprefix = "[gitolite repo pushed]"
desc = "gitolite repo"
```

I have not been able to figure out where else mailinglist is set. Any ideas why I am getting this warning?

Comment: FWIW a similar message to me meant "edit your .gitmodules file and remove a double entry in it"

Answer (score 1):

Try and go within one of the bare repos managed by gitolite and do a

```
git config -l
```

That will list all configs in all [three git config files (local, global and system)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11748140/6309), in [the right order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1881665/6309).

You can then [unset the extra config](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6529889/6309) in the right config file (as, for instance, in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6435291/6309)).

```
git config --system (or --global or --local) --unset hooks.announcelist
git config --system (or --global or --local) --unset-all hooks.announcelist
```

Comment: Only a single hooks.announcelist and hooks.emailinglist is shown.

Comment: @ScotWilkie can you do the `config -l` from within the `gitolite-admin` repo itself? I realise the issue should come from the config of thet repo, and not of the ones managed by gitolite.

Comment: yes I got into the bare gitolite-admin repo on our git server and ran `git config -l`. Only a single hooks.emailinglist was listed. There is also a user.email which is set the gitadmin user email address. But I believe this is the senders email address, not the recipients.